# Getting the next record id with only one known value

Tags: mysql

I have a telephone number which i want to use to get the next record id using `limit value,1` method.

This is my sql code

```
select id as next_id 
from transactions 
where tel = '44723954537' 
AND id = (select id from transactions where tel = '44723954537') 
LIMIT (select id from transactions where tel = '44723954537'),1
```

When i run the code,i get this error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LIMIT (select id from transactions where tel = '44723954537'),1)
>   LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

How should i write my limit statement?.

Comment: Try just LIMIT 1 in the end

Comment: I am expecting the final statement to be LIMIT 1200,1 for instance that should give me the next record.I cannot drop the last fetch id part.

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause doesn't allow expressions, they have to be literal values.

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make sense. "next" only makes sense when the results are ordered, but you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT min(id) AS next_id
FROM transactions
WHERE id > (SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM transactions
            WHERE tel = '4472395437')
```

This will find the next record after the last record with the given telephone number.